# Selenium using proxy when creating driver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy

for a long time i used the following code to create a selenium-driver for chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

HOSTNAME = "109.175.226.252"
PORT = "12345"
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = prox.ssl_proxy = f"{HOSTNAME}:{PORT}"
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

But recently i get the following error when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\jonpetrich\collSuperATV.py", line 97, in <module>
    prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
AttributeError: 'Proxy' object has no attribute 'add_to_capabilities'
```

How can i use my proxies with selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase for it.

Set the proxy in `HOST:PORT` format or `USER:PASS@HOST:PORT` format. Eg:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", proxy="109.175.226.252:12345")
```

You'll need to set a valid proxy. (The one from your example wasn't active.)

Comment: Thx a lot - but i would like to create the driver the same way i did it before
(withtout using SeleniumBase)

Comment: To do proxy with authentication in regular selenium requires either creating a zipped chrome extension with the proxy config details (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35293284/7058266) or a selenium framework that does those things for you. But if you just want a regular proxy without auth, it's just `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=IP:PORT')` now.

Comment: Thx - i think this works now using the above format with USER:PASS@HOST:PORT and seleniumbase like you described it in your solution. I also found that i can use the parameters (uc= and headless= for undectectedchromebrowser and headless). But  was not able to find a comprehensive overivew of all the potential parameters for the Driver-generation - maybe you also know where to find this documentaton exactly?

Comment: The full list of `Driver()` args can be found here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py