# headless taking twice as long to run as compared to non-headless? Seleniumbase Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, headless, seleniumbase

I have this code that scrapes a website for pricing data, just for one particular product. However, making it headless makes it run twice as slow as compared to without headless. Shouldn't it be faster to be running headless instead of without? What is causing this issue??? Running on a browser takes about 6 seconds from start to finish. Running it headless takes 13 seconds instead.

```
timerstart = time.time()
url ='https://www.newegg.com/global/sg-en/corsair-32gb/p/N82E16820236991?Item=N82E16820236991&cm_sp=Homepage_SS-_-P2_20-236-991-_-01072024'

driver = Driver(uc=True, block_images=True, headless=True)
driver.get(url)
dollars = driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/strong").text 
cents = driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/sup").text
priceofproduct = ""
priceofproduct = str(dollars)+str(cents)
priceofproduct = float(priceofproduct)
print(priceofproduct)
driver.close()
timerend = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: " + str(timerend-timerstart))
```

Comment: Have you tested this for other sites? It's possible that newegg specifically detects and slows headless browsers. Unlikely, but it's worth considering.

Comment: The virtual display is better than headless mode for situations like this. See the second half of the following solution for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77834448/7058266