# Running selenium behind a proxy server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, web-scraping

I have been using selenium for automatic browser simulations and web scraping in python and it has worked well for me. But now, I have to run it behind a proxy server. So now selenium open up the window but could not open the requested page because of proxy settings not set on the opened browser. Current code is as follows (sample):

```
from selenium import webdriver

sel = webdriver.Firefox()
sel.get('http://www.google.com')
sel.title
sel.quit()
```

How do I change the above code to work with proxy server now as well?

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38168865/5409601

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to set desired capabilities or browser profile, like this:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "proxy.server.address")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", "port_number")
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Also see related threads:

- [how do i set proxy for chrome in python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver)
- [Selenium using Python: enter/provide http proxy password for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885137/selenium-using-python-enter-provide-http-proxy-password-for-firefox)
- [Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python)
- http://krosinski.blogspot.ru/2012/11/selenium-firefox-webdriver-and-proxies.html

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still not able to get past the proxy server

Comment: I checked the browser settings opened by selenium after doing the preference update. Actually issue is that, it is not setting http_port correctly (and leaving it out to be 0), because of which it is not connecting. Are there any issues in port setting ?

Comment: Hm, can you try setting it as a number (not string)?

Comment: I was doing a stupid error. Basically, you dont need to put the port number under braces. It works well now.

Comment: how to do the same thing for phantomjs. Basically,instead of ` profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()  profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())`,i want to use phantomjs for same proxy server.

Answer (score 8):

The official Selenium documentation (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) provides clear and helpful guidelines about using a proxy.
For Firefox (which is the browser of choice in your sample code) you should do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

myProxy = "host:8080"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

proxyHost = "my.proxy.host or IP"
proxyPort = "55555"

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
#fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxyHost) #HTTP PROXY
#fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(proxyPort))
#fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", proxyHost) #SSL  PROXY
#fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", int(proxyPort))
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', proxyHost) #SOCKS PROXY
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', int(proxyPort))
fp.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get("http://www.whatismyip.com/")
```

Comment: how to add user:pass

Comment: Important to note: if `proxyHost` is a hostname should not contain the _"http://"_ prefix

Comment: @UmairAyub have you found a solution for adding user:pass?

Answer (score 2):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

proxy = "xxx.xx.xx.xxxx"
port = 8080

options = Options()
options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", port)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.https", proxy)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port", port)

ser = Service(r"C:/Users/geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=ser, options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def install_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    print PROXY_PORT
    print PROXY_HOST
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",int(PROXY_PORT))  
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port",int(PROXY_PORT))   
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(PROXY_PORT))   
    fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A")
    fp.update_preferences()
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```