# Change Google Chrome Settings using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am a basic python programmer.
I would like to change the settings of google chrome, especially the proxy and LAN settings automatically with a program.
I tried looking at the webbrowser library, but I don't think its sufficient.
I looked at the selenium library, but I do not know where to start looking for my requirements in the library, could someone provide a resource or a method on how to automate my tasks? I looked at another questions which describes a process using c#. But thats not my problem. I want the required documentation for my exact purpose.

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html

which of these must I use?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the [Selenium WebDriver API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver), with Python bindings (lots of other languages are also supported, and many frameworks are available).

Here's a [good Python example](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html), plus there's a [huge number of helpful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver+python?sort=votes&pageSize=15) on this site.

[Here's a good description of the ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) (the WebDriver library that automates a Chrome browser) complete with installation instructions and example Python code.

I personally recommend [BrowserMob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium) as a proxy server for Selenium. Although it's Java-based, once it's running you can control it via a REST API - I assume you want to be able to manipulate requests/responses, that kind of thing?

In any case, there are lots of proxy servers available, and the configuration to use one within your Python code is pretty standard. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17988970/954442) (see also the links).

Comment: The Chrome Driver link is down.

Comment: Works for me... that's a Google site.