# How to automate basic authentication chrome alert

Tags: java, google-chrome, authentication, selenium-chromedriver, alert

[image: Chrome authentication popup]

Have tried several approached to handle it but none worked.

1. `https://user:password@pageaddress.com` - doesn't work, chrome launches controlled bu automates test software and authentication pop-up appears anyway.
2. Adding `--disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources` to Chrome arg and repeat 1'st point - doesn't work, reason the same as in 1'st point.
3. `driver.switchTo().alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(user, password))` - here seems like driver doesn't see an alert, have impelented method that checks it and returns false:

   `private Alert alert;
    public boolean isAlertPresent() {
       try {
           waitForTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
           return true;
       } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
           return false;
       }}`
4. Triggering keyboard or mouse event via selenium `Action()` doesn't work too.

   `chromedriver 2.31
   Google Chrome Version 61`

Any other ideas ? Maybe some js script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally - I was able to do it by Robot Framework which is not a solution that I am proud of, but didn't have any other idea.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

private Robot robot;

public void login(String login, String password) {
    copyValueFromClipboardToInput(login);
    getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    getRobot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    copyValueFromClipboardToInput(password);
    getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    getRobot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}

private void copyValueFromClipboardToInput(String value) {
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(value), null);
    getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    getRobot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    getRobot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    getRobot().keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}

private Robot getRobot() {
    if (robot == null) {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return robot;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629531/how-to-pass-pass-user-credentials-to-chrome-via-native-messaging-api).
you may not need the full Native Messaging API, though ...
This will all be JavaScript and will work for any browser-generated auth request (at least, it looks that way).

webRequest - [chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onAuthRequired) - has an anAuthRequired event.
You can hook into this with a listener then just pass in the credentials you need per some [examples](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/JavaScript.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/WebRequest/onAuthRequired.html#Examples).

If you're wanting to just pass in user credentials that won't change, you'll want to use the synchronous method - it's much easier. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885137/selenium-using-python-enter-provide-http-proxy-password-for-firefox) may, indeed, be all you need.

If you're needing to pass in different credentials, you may well want to look into the asynchronous method, that's the one I had to use.
If you're using chrome, forget [promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks) ... but Firefox should work with them.

Hope this helped!