# got exception while initialize chromedriver with proxy file selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to initialize chrome webdriver with proxy. I found a solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885137/selenium-using-python-enter-provide-http-proxy-password-for-firefox/35293222). I did just like this but got exception like this.

```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35 (0),platform=Linux 4.4.0-122-generic x86_64)
```

As I need to created to file described in the link, here is my background.js

```
var config = {
                mode: "fixed_servers",
                rules: {
                  singleProxy: {
                    scheme: "http",
                    host: "172.241.11.1", //modified it for privacy
                    port: parseInt(29842)
                  },
                  bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
                }
              };

        chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

        function callbackFn(details) {
            return {
                authCredentials: {
                    username: "aedqbb01",
                    password: "ac7DMjR"
                }
            };
        }

        chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                    callbackFn,
                    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                    ['blocking']
        );
```

and manifest.json

```
{
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "manifest_version": 2,
            "name": "Chrome Proxy",
            "permissions": [
                "proxy",
                "tabs",
                "unlimitedStorage",
                "storage",
                "<all_urls>",
                "webRequest",
                "webRequestBlocking"
            ],
            "background": {
                "scripts": ["background.js"]
            },
            "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
        }
```

and here is my python program

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0")
chrome_options.add_extension("proxy.zip") #where is manifest.json and background.json 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
```

Code works fine without proxy file.

I did I missing here. Please correct me.

Comment: _Selenium Client_ / _WebDriver_ / _WebClient_ variant and version info please?

Comment: selenium version- 3.11., Google Chrome version -65.0.3325.181 , Chromium version-65.0.3325.181, ChromeDriver 2.35 (0)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.11.0**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.1.0* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.35*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* version to current ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: updated chromedriver to(2.38.552522), Google Chrome 66.0.3359.139
Got error again

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://nkfjhnfkkgabeghamphipepjpbcjkkfd/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://nkfjhnfkkgabeghamphipepjpbcjkkfd/_generated_background_page.html

Comment: @DipDeb I have solved this question for the error you were seeing as **selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally**. Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?