# Proxy authentication popup in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a project where I need to use a proxy. I am using the Chrome browser and when I run my script it forces me to enter the username and password of the proxy.

I have tried passing the username and password with the URL itself, but it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
Proxy p = new Proxy();
p.setHttpProxy("in-pr.oxylabs.io:20000");
p.setSslProxy("in-pr.oxylabs.io:20000");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Love_Testing\\Senium_Naveen\\chrome Driver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//  options.addArguments("--incognito");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
dc.setCapability("proxy",p);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: do you want to disable the proxy on chrome browser ?and not to get any popup for asking the username and password ?

Comment: I want to enter the username and password in that popup

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: Not any error, I tried passing the username and password with url itself but it is not working @RamanaMuttana

Comment: can you add the code ,,making the driver to go to popup is not through url , it can done by   Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

Comment: Not able to switch to alert

Comment: @RamanaMuttana Please check the code

Comment: dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,p); change this line

Comment: After changing what should i do because alert is still not working

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/  create one AUTOIT script.exe and run with it ..WinWaitActive("Authentication Login") send("validusername") send("{TAB}") send("Validpassword") send("{ENTER}")  add path of this exe before your opening url

Comment: problem is after driver.get("www.google.com")   No instruction is running

Comment: did you read the above comment and tried ? 1)the first question is did the popup is appearing before the driver.get("www.google.com") or after the driver.get("www.google.com")?. if the popup appears before the driver tries to open the google.com,, then add the AUTOIT script.exe file before driver.get("www.google.com").

Comment: Yes ;popup is appearing before driver.get()

Comment: then follow the above comment code and link provided and tell me the results

Comment: Proxy p = new Proxy(); p.setHttpProxy("in-pr.oxylabs.io:20000");
p.setSslProxy("in-pr.oxylabs.io:20000");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,p);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(dc); Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path");

Comment: tried this code but not working

Comment: I have already watch that video but issue is same

Comment: try driver.get( "http://username:password@google.com"); once

Comment: i tried like driver.get("https://username:password@google.com"); but did not work

Comment: username and password are :  your username and your password

Comment: username is love and password is also love

Comment: i mean did you tried with your credientials ? i am not asking for you to mention .what is the result now ?

Comment: you mean manually

Comment: no , with driver only

Comment: yes tried with driver and it is still showing me the authentication popup

Comment: Try with "MultiPass for HTTP basic authentication" chrome extension

Comment: how to use http basic authentication

Comment: add the extension to chrome , search once  "how to add the extensions to chrome" and search for the extension and add and try

Comment: "not working" is not a useful problem description. Please be more specific.

Comment: It is still showing authentication

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? having a similar issue

Comment: I used autoit to handle popup

Answer (score 2):

There's a small Chrome plugin that you can build manually [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35293222/7037546).
To apply the plugin, in a java context:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File("proxy.zip"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```