# Watir - use proxy with authentication

Tags: selenium, watir

How can you use a proxy with authentication with Watir?

From the [documentation](http://watir.com/guides/proxies/)

```
proxy = {
  http: 'my.proxy.com:8080',
  ssl:  'my.proxy.com:8080'
}
chrome_browser  = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, proxy: proxy
```

My proxy is structured like `ip:port:username:password` and doesn't appear to be working. How can I use this proxy with Watir?

Comment: did you try `...http: 'http://username:password@my.proxy.com:8080'...`

Comment: What @kiril said, and also I believe it's https not ssl

Comment: @pguardiario its def. `ssl`! @Kiril S. doesn't work. I'm trying this as well and have problems with it.

Comment: @TheMiniJohn my research showed it isn't possible to use proxies with watir

Answer (score 1):

For posterity:

You can use https://github.com/SebastianJ/proxy-chain-rb to setup a proxy on localhost without authentication that redirects to your actual proxy.

```
real_proxy = "http://username:password@host:port"
server = ProxyChainRb::Server.new
generated_proxy = server.start(real_proxy)

proxy = {
  http: generated_proxy,
  ssl:  generated_proxy
}

Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, proxy: proxy)

* do your scraping *

server.stop
```

If running headless mode is not a requirement, you can also use an extension.

Create the zip file described in [Selenium using Python: enter/provide http proxy password for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885137/selenium-using-python-enter-provide-http-proxy-password-for-firefox/35293222) (obviously, with your own proxy information).

Create a `.crx` file from the zip. You can do this in Chrome -> Settings -> Extensions -> toggle Developer mode -> Pack extension

```
options = { extensions: ['path of .crx file'] }
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: options
```

Do note that this will not work in headless Chrome.