# How to add a proxy with authentication for chrome selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I'm using selenium 3.141.0 with python 3.9 and chrome webdriver, I've managed to make my bot do the actions I require on the pages, but I can't find a way to make it work with a proxy.(For the proxy I'm using NORDVPN)

Until now I tried a class that creates a manifest_json and a background.js and archives them so it uses them as an addon, and I get multiple errors depending on the port I use:
tunneling error, page refused to send data or time out

Comment: Are you using the NORDVPN chrome extension or computer app?

Comment: I'm having the computer app, if I use it, it works, but I want to automate the process and change the proxy on every iteration, thought I could code it somehow into python. For the ip from NORDVPN I've pinged the host in cmd and saved the ip's were I got a response, not sure which port I should use though

Comment: If anyone need the solution, this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885137/selenium-using-python-enter-provide-http-proxy-password-for-firefox/35293222#35293222) worked fine for me.